# Number formatting

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, choice-field, number

I have a two **choice columns** that display same three choices: 0, 3, 9

Column 1 has a value of 9

Column 2 has a value of 3

I want to add 9 and 3 on a new column.

Something so simple is giving me issues?
Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two columns named: `Choice1` and `Choice1`.

Then you can create a new **Calculated column** in your list and use below formula:

```
=[Choice1]+[Choice1]
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Microsoft official Reference**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

Comment: Ganesh, thanks  amillion for your support!
It worked :)

Comment: Hi @Jose1978, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with same problem in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.